# Issue on integrating Database cleaner gem in Ruby Rspec automation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rspec

I am getting the following error on executing the code.

**No known ORM was detected!  Is ActiveRecord, DataMapper, Sequel, MongoMapper, Mongoid, Moped, or CouchPotato, Redis or Ohm loaded? (DatabaseCleaner::NoORMDetected)**

Can anyone pls suggest a solution for this.

**spec_helper.rb:**

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

require 'database_cleaner'
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/database_cleaner.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :mocha

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    #Mongoid.master.collections.select {|c| c.name !~ /system/ }.each(&:drop) # transactional fixtures hack for mongo
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = [:should, :expect]
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.color = true

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

Comment: Have you defined a model?

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps. Here is how I have my (working) database cleaner configured:

1. I have no `database_cleaner.rb`. I configure everything in `rails_helper.rb`. This shouldn't matter, but you may want to try below code and see if it works before splitting it out.
2. Notice that I have `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` in a `before` block
3. Here is the relevant part of my `rails_helper.rb`

   ```
   RSpec.configure do |config|
     config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

     config.before(:suite) do
       DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation
     end

     config.before(:each) do |example|
       if example.metadata[:js]
         DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
       else
         DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
       end
       DatabaseCleaner.start
     end

     config.after(:each) do
       DatabaseCleaner.clean
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your `RSpec.configure` block:

```
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
```

Also, to specify particular ORM, you can do this:

```
#How to specify particular orms
DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].strategy = :transaction
DatabaseCleaner[:mongo_mapper].strategy = :truncation
```

See [this](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#how-to-use-with-multiple-orms) for more information.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I have added the above given code Rspec.configure block in spec_helper.rb; However, facing the same issue. Pls help me on this.

Comment: I have shown spec_helper.rb and database_cleaner.rb above. Pls have a look above.